# Who exactly is Archer from the Unlimited Blade Works movie?

Tags: fate-stay-night

Although I have not watched the *Fate/Zero* TV series, I have watched the *Fate/stay night* series and the *Fate/Stay Night - Unlimited Blade Works* movie. At the end of the movie I found out that:

> Archer is actually Shirō. Even before the ending, Archer told him he has already experienced what Shirō goes through. So I did not know if he is actually Shirō from the future or if he is a completely different character than the one in the TV series.

Comment: Can you point to the episode and time where he mentions that? I don't recall ever hearing something like this.

Comment: @Mysticial He mentions it in the movie, actually.  Apparently hero summoning transcends the future, too.

Comment: That's because he said it in the movie.
He may have said this series but I do not remember as well.

Comment: @fbueckert Ah ok. I haven't seen the movies, that why I never saw.

Comment: @Mysticial I'd highly recommend it; it's essentially a modified retelling of the series, but there are some points (such as this one) that stand out.

Comment: Is it the TV reproduction? I checked my MAL, and I actually *have* seen it. But it was probably a while back.

Comment: @Mysticial, it takes the Unlimited Blade Works route (Rin route), instead of the Fate route (Saber route) of the TV series.

Comment: @Krazer, then I haven't seen it. The TV reproduction is just a condensed version of the main series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Archer-class Servant in the fifth Fuyuki Grail War is:

> Shirou Emiya from an alternate timeline than that of the *Fate/stay night* timeline. The Shirou from the alternate timeline made a contract with [the world](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gaia#Alaya) and became the Heroic Spirit EMIYA.
>
> He is not a proper [Heroic Spirit](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Heroic_Spirit) in the sense of other heroes (e.g. Saber, Lancer, Berserker). He acts as a [Counter Guardian](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Counter_Guardian#Counter_Guardian) for the world as payment for the contract. 
>  He is summoned because he still has the jewel pendant that Rin used to save his life after Lancer stabbed his heart. The jewel he owns is the actual catalyst used for his summoning rather than the one that Rin still has at the time of his summoning.